# Teradata : Extract Date from string

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

There is a notation field with different number of characters. Eg

```
Exceed Limit Fee 26-January-2020
```

or

```
Account Exceed Limit Fee 05-June-2001
```

I want to extract date part of it and convert that to date type. After that compare it with date field of other table.

How can I achieve this in Teradata?

Comment: Is the date format fixed: two digit day, full month and four digit year? Always at the end of the string?

Comment: @dnoeth Yes, date is in the same format two digit day- full month- four digit year at the end of string

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the date using a RegEx and then cast to a date:

```
to_date(regexp_substr(x, '\d{1,2}-\w{3,9}-\d{4}'), 'dd-month-yyyy')
```

This is s basic regex checking for two-digit day a string and a -digit year. You could enhance it to match a correct month name, 'January', etc., just search for a PCRE2 compatible RegEx.

Comment: Thankyou @dnoeth for taking out your time. This worked 